# Best C# syntax for ignoring an exception

Tags: c#, exception

There are some cases we don't care about the `Exception` and just need to resume. I know it's side-effects and ...

Here my question is about the best `C#` syntax for ignoring an `exception`, for example:

```
try
{
   // exceptional code
}
catch { }
```

but this seems a little ugly specially that empty brackets after `catch`. Is there a more elegant syntax ?

Comment: Yeah, add a comment explaining why you swallow it.

Comment: That's what I do. I don't see how you can make it much more elegant.

Comment: Well, at least add a trace in the catch block.

Comment: catch { /* you are not supposed to understand why */ }

Comment: This has been asked before; I just can't find it. Anyone?

Comment: Did you also write the code that goes inside the try? Can you re-write it so it doesn't throw?

Comment: @Esteban: There are some .net routines like Control.BeginInvoke which have practically-unsolvable race conditions.  If an asynchronous event should change what is displayed on a control, it should BeginInvoke an update routine on that control.  If the control gets disposed just before the BeginInvoke occurs, there's no way to avoid having it throw an exception.  While one could acquire a lock in both Dispose and BeginInvoke, it's cleaner to try the BeginInvoke and swallow the exception.  Probably a good idea, though, to wrap the Catch and BeginInvoke in a TryBeginInvoke method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best route, but you could do this to be a little more descriptive:

```
try
{
    //  exceptional code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

However, I think the empty brackets convey the same message to whoever is maintaining this in the future.

Better still would be to refactor your exceptional code. If you're ignoring an exception, chances are it could (and should) be done a better way.

Comment: Isn't `continue` going to be a loop control statement, if that `try` block is inside a loop? And a syntax error if it isn't?

Comment: I don't completely agree with the last line either.  Sometimes (rarely I will admit) you honestly don't care and you can safely move past an exception.  That said, I don't recall ever doing such a thing in production code, just internal stuff.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove the incorrect continue statement. I stand behind the last line, though @Ed. Internal stuff, sure, if you're not deploying to production I guess that makes sense. But "exceptional code" should be treated as such, and if there is no reason for the exception since it will be ignored, why throw it?

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it the fewer reasons I can come up with.  At least throw a trace in there or something.

Comment: +1 for the same syntax as question (after removing `continue`)

Answer (score 4):

You should never have an empty `catch` statement like that. Having an error in the code and not even noticing it is worse than just having an error in the code.

If you really want to catch exceptions and ignore them, try to catch only the type of exception that you want to ignore, and add a comment about the reason for ignoring it:

```
try {
  // exceptional code...
} catch(FormatException) {
  // A comment describing why on earth you are cathing
  // an exception and ignoring it.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ummm.. I don't think there is anything "inelegant" about the two braces (the fact that you're swallowing exceptions with not so much as a comment is however).  You must have better problems to worry about.

Comment: *You must have better problems to worry about*. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think convention would be that typically when ignoring exceptions, you are ignoring exceptions of a specific type and at least providing some handling for System.Exception. Either way, I would document in the catch why the corresponding exception is being ignored.

```
try {

   ... exceptional code

} catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
   // This exception can be ignored because ..
} catch (Exception ex) {
   ... error handling code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring.NET AOP

[Exception Handler Advice](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.1-RC1/sdk/1.1/html/Spring.Aop~Spring.Aspects.Exceptions.ExceptionHandlerAdvice.html)

**Excerpts from the link**

The source exceptions to perform processing on are listed immediately after the keyword 'on' and can be comma delmited. Following that is the action to perform, either log, translate, wrap, replace, return, or **swallow.**